# Visual Studio blocking with modal publish dialog

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2012

Simply trying to publish a web service through Visual Studio 2012 like I always do, and everything locks up.  You see a quick flash of a publish dialog, then it disappears - nothing can be done but to kill the process.  My Azure publish works fine, but other projects like MVC do the same locking behavior.  I can't alt-tab to anything, I have found no other solution then to kill it.  Any ideas?  Attached is the error I get if I try to restart.

[image]

P.S. I have tried restarting and no add-ins are installed.

Comment: Troubleshooting this needs to start by disabling add-ins one by one.  If that doesn't get you anywhere then use connect.microsoft.com to file a feedback report.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually turned out to be the first signs of a hardware failure... Apple... never again.

Comment: Oh boy I hope that's not the case.. same thing happening to me on a 2 month old mbpr..